# Changing the background color of the text in react native when it is pressed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to change my text (heading and body) background-color, when the text press me is pressed.  I have no clue how to connect change the current state when the text 'press me' is clicked. I have my app.js and styles.js connected to one another.

Here is what I have so far in app.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from './styles.js';
export default function TextInANest() {
  const [titleText, setTitleText] = useState('First Text');
  const [bodyText, setBodyText] = useState('Second Text!');

  onPressTitle = () => {
    if (titleText == 'First Text' && bodyText == 'Second Text!') {

      setTitleText('First Text After');
      setBodyText('Second Text After!');
    }
    else if (titleText == 'First Text After' && bodyText == 'Second Text After!') {
      setTitleText('Second Text');
      setBodyText('Second Text!');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.baseText} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        {/* <TouchableHighlight {...touchProps}> */}
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>
            {titleText}{'\n'}{'\n'}</Text>
         {/* </TouchableHighlight> */}
          <Text style={styles.bodyText} numberOfLines={5}>
            {bodyText}{'\n'}{'\n'}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      <View >
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={onPressTitle}>
          <Text style={styles.pressMe}>Press Me!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here is what I have so far in styles.js:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lavender',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  baseText: {
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor:'#ddffd0',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  bodyText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor:'#adf4e0',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  titleTextAft: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor:'#adf4e0',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  bodyTextAft: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor:'#ddffd0',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  pressMe:{
    fontSize: 23,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#ff0000',
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
}
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply have another state variable or use any condition and set the style you need for the Text value.
Here i have use the styleToggle and done that.

As you can see the condition

```
<Text style={styleToggle? styles.bodyText:styles.bodyTextAft} numberOfLines={5}>
```

Decides the style to be used.

You can see the full code below.

```
 const [styleToggle,setStyleToggle]=useState(true);

  const onPressTitle = () => {
    if (titleText == 'First Text' && bodyText == 'Second Text!') {

      setTitleText('First Text After');
      setBodyText('Second Text After!');
    }
    else if (titleText == 'First Text After' && bodyText == 'Second Text After!') {
      setTitleText('Second Text');
      setBodyText('Second Text!');
    }

    setStyleToggle(!styleToggle);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.baseText} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        {/* <TouchableHighlight {...touchProps}> */}
        <Text style={styleToggle? styles.titleText:styles.titleTextAft}>
            {titleText}{'\n'}{'\n'}</Text>
         {/* </TouchableHighlight> */}
          <Text style={styleToggle? styles.bodyText:styles.bodyTextAft} numberOfLines={5}>
            {bodyText}{'\n'}{'\n'}
          </Text>
        </Text>
      <View >
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={onPressTitle}>
          <Text style={styles.pressMe}>Press Me!</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```